# CATransaction commit crash because of EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build, xcode10

[CATransaction commit] crash because of EXC_BAD_ACCESS,CATransaction is a class,how could it be nil!
I check the apple profile,I find Apple explain that 'Raises an exception if no current transaction exists.', So I doubt it that no current transaction exists.But I know't how to determine whether a transaction exists.

Comment: Without including any code for how you're initializing and using the `CATransaction` it's nearly impossible to diagnose.

Comment: Now I find that I set layer.contents = (__bridge id)obj.contentImg.CGImage will cause crash.

Comment: I set layer.contents and the image is  too big  size {11184832, 20},and I think it is too big cause crash.But I don't know why

Comment: Perhaps you can post part of the symbolicated crash log.

Comment: If you are loading an image that big, it will take up 8 x image width x image height bytes in memory on a wide color device. At the size you're describing, you're likely getting killed because you're using too much memory. There was a WWDC 2018 session describing techniques for downsampling that might help. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/219/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've balanced your calls to `[CATransaction begin]` and `[CATransaction commit]`

Comment: yes,I call commit before begin ,and They come in pairs

Comment: `[CATransaction begin]` should be called before making changes and calling `commit` to create the transaction. If you need to flush any implicit transaction state, call `[CATransaction flush]` before `begin`. Just clarifying because your comment above says the opposite.